# How exclude some paths from @GetMapping spring annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use `Spring Boot` and my main controller handles all top urls:

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping({"/*"})
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleIndex() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And for some reasons I want exclude path `/exclude_path` from handling of my controller.

Something like this:

```
@GetMapping(include={"/*"}, exclude={"/exclude_path"})
```

Could you please answer how I may do this?

Comment: if you don't put it in the GetMapping it will not be handled. Not sure what is the question here.

Comment: @pvpkiran, I have wildcard `/*` in my path, and want exclude only one url (/exclude_path) that maps to this wildcard.

Comment: just add another mapping for that specific handling, like "AcccessNotAllowed" or 404NotFound somthing like that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `/*` is a bad practice. If at all you want to do it, your best option would be to introduce an Aspect for your controller. And filter it out there.
Something like this will do:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
public void requestMapping() {}

@Pointcut("within(blah.blah.package.controller.*)")
public void myController() {}

@Around("requestMapping() && myController()")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {  
    String url = requestMapping.value();
    // check the url and based on that do  
    // joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: this answer is over kill for question.

Answer (score -1):

You should remove “/*” as it will except all the requests. Provide only the path you want so you don’t need /excludepath.

Comment: I have single page application, and I don't manage frontend. If I remove `/*` than I will have to write every new url in my code.